# Google Places API Difference between _id and place_id

Tags: google-places-api

Could someone please explain me the key difference between the attributes: _id and place_id?

I know: Place IDs uniquely identify a place in the Google Places database and on Google Maps.

But what does the attribute _key representing ?

Example Response Code from the Google Api:

```
    {
        "_id": "d5bcd8db4a52088350ffb502c31c6694918d3907",
        "place_id": "ChIJb3D1a2mnkUcRxop5hdAGiwY",
        "lat": 27.991789,
        "lng": 3.865653,
        "name": "We Are here",
        "rating": 0,
        "user_ratings_total": 0,
        "types": [
            "school",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `_id` field was deprecated and should disappear from responses shortly.

> The Places fields `reference`, `id`, `alt_id`, and `scope` are deprecated as of September 3, 2019, and will be turned off on June 3, 2020.
>
> The **id and reference request parameters have been replaced by the place_id request parameter**.
>   the alt_id and scope fields have no equivalent, as they were only used for the Place Add service which was turned off in July 2018.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/deprecations#places_fields_reference_id_alt_id_scope_-

I guess Google just renamed deprecated `id` field as `_id`.